# How to manage Ajax success function?

Tags: php, json, ajax

```
  if (isset($_POST["getCanvas"]) ) {  
               $projectName= mysqli_real_escape_string($db2, $_POST['whichProject']);
              $query = "SELECT objectsList FROM projectObjectstable  WHERE projectName='$projectName'";
            //  $query = "SELECT objectsList,backgroundImage FROM projectObjectstable  WHERE projectName='$projectName'";
               $jsonCanvas= mysqli_query($db2,$query);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($jsonCanvas);
                    $myLine=$row['0'];
                    echo $myLine;
       }
```

With code above i get one column from table. I need two columns. I woud like to try  next:

```
          $query = "SELECT objectsList FROM projectObjectstable  WHERE projectName='$projectName'";
          $jsonCanvas= mysqli_query($db2,$query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($jsonCanvas);
                $myLine=$row['0'];
                echo $myLine;
             $query2 = "SELECT backgroundImage FROM projectObjectstable  WHERE projectName='$projectName'";
             $jsonBackground= mysqli_query($db2,$query2);
                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($jsonBackground);
                    $myLine2=$row['0'];
                    echo $myLine2;
       }
```

For it I need next solution here. How to modificate  ajax success function to get two variables (projectList and backgroundImage) on canvas?

```
$.ajax({
  method:"POST",
  url: '/wp-content/themes/mypage3/PgetJson.php',
  data:  {
    "getCanvas":1,
    "whichProject":whichProjectToSave
    },
    datatype: "text",
    success: function(strdate){
     canvas.loadFromJSON(strdate, function() {
     canvas.renderAll();
      });
     }
 });
```

An extra information would e appreciated. What options exists to debug php code in browser, as it is possible to do with js ?
Thank you

Comment: Start with learning about json.

Comment: create a array of your data and then json_encode it and send to ajax success and there decode it and traverse it and use all values

Comment: With Ajax it is type and not method

Answer (score 0):

As it was said before, you need to use json_encode function to send parameters in JSON format to your JS. You have to put your variables inside an array before calling to echo. As it's used below.

```
         $query = "SELECT objectsList FROM projectObjectstable  
                   WHERE projectName='$projectName'";
         $_row= mysqli_query($db2,$query);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_row($_row);
         $jsonCanvas=$row['0'];

         $query2 = "SELECT backgroundImage FROM projectObjectstable  
                    WHERE projectName='.$projectName.'";
         $_row2= mysqli_query($db2,$query2);
         $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($_row2);
         $jsonBackground=$row['0'];

         $to_json['jsonCanvas'] = $jsonCanvas;
         $to_json['jsonBackground'] = $jsonBackground;

         echo json_encode($to_json);
         exit();
```

And in your JS, you collect your information in the success function:

```
$.ajax({
  method:"POST",
  url: '/wp-content/themes/mypage3/PgetJson.php',
  data:  {
    "getCanvas":1,
    "whichProject":whichProjectToSave
    },
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(strdate){
      /*Here on data you will receive
      strdate['jsonCanvas'] & strdate['jsonBackground']
      */
      });
     }
 });
```

I would also recommend making your sql calls in one query if your calling to the same table and passing the same variable as an argument.

Comment: I was hoping to understand and then to proceed with displaying everything in console (console.log(strdate);) to see what i am getting back.  And i am out. Can you help me more pleas? I need to  put background and objects  on canvas.

Comment: @ivangolubar I don't specifically understand what you are trying to do. 
Write the console log in the success function to see if the data received is correct. If you want to use that information to create elements in HTML and then appending them to canvas you can use document.createElement and jQuery's append(). Tell me if that works